# VueJS: Passing data from root element to child components through router-view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuex

Generally, when I have a variable that several child components should be able to access, I store them in the data object of my root Vue element and subsequently pass them down to child components through properties.

However, I've recently progressed to using vue-router and my root vue element only contains a "router-view" component, which controls what child component is being served to the user.

**Below is what my root element looks like (I am using vue-cli):**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app'
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

As a result, the approach of passing variables to child components through properties, which I used prior to using vue router, doesn't seem viable anymore.

**How should I be passing data from my root Vue element to my child components through vue router? Should I even be using this approach to achieve my goal of accessing "global" variables?**

I've read several threads that reference using Vuex for state management and while I'm unopposed to learning and using it - it feels a little overkill for what I'm trying to achieve at this stage.

EDIT (clarifying question)

Several of my child components make API calls to a local / production server (depending on the node environment) and I find myself copying the “if-else” logic multiple times to determine which server the component should be making the API call to. So I thought it would be a much better approach of declaring a “server” variable at the root element and then pass it down to the child elements that need to make API calls

Answer (score 2):

Vuex is a great tool, however, if you're trying to pass some basic data - such as a record id - to a child component, you should be looking at route props.

https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html

With route route props, you declare props in your child components in the normal fashion. However, the must be named the same are the route property.

```
// child component
props: ['id']

// route definition
{ path: '/item/:id', component: Item, props: true },
```

As you can see the `:id` is then passed to the child component `id` prop.

As your application grows in it's complexity, vuex (or a state manager of your choosing) would be a much more appropriate tool to use. When you become comfortable with it and learn some of the really nice tricks, you'll see what you've been missing :).

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quick. Since I’m looking to pass variables that are unspecific to the routes - I’m not sure that’s the best approach for my specific case. For example, several of my child components make API calls to a local / production server (depending on the node environment) and I find myself copying the “if” statement logic multiple times. So I thought it would be a much better approach of declaring a “server” variable at the root element and then passing it down to the child elements that need it to make API calls.

Comment: Imo, that's another reason to be using a state management system. Here's why: I use vuex `actions` to make my api calls. Each module has your typical CRUD routes plus any specific routes defined and wrapped in an action. i.e. action named fetchUser, within the action  axios makes the api request. The response is stored in state and my child components have computeds (using mapGetters) to reactively act when the response is received. If I need to set data before the api call, the parent component simple sets it in the store. Can you give an example of a specific use case you have?

Comment: Another thought, maybe dynamic components would be useful in your case. Create a specific component for each case and instantiate the appropriate one based on which server you need to call. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: Based off what you just described - it seems like I should look into Vuex. Im building a CRUD application to learn Vue and some of my components are also using axios to make API requests to my server. E.g I will have a “getLocation” function within the methods object of the child component which is responsible for fetching a location from the server. In order to build the request URL for axios, I have my if statement which determines which server to use, which is the repetitive part at the moment that I’m trying to eliminate.

Comment: I think it would be the right choice. Like I said, as your app grows and you become more familiar with vuex it'll seem like a no brainer. Here is an example of axios used with a store. https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/416oz6ga/

Comment: Thanks for the advice - really appreciate it. Time to look into Vuex  May I ask, outside of reading the docs, were there any other resources you found to be useful?

Comment: alligator.io has some good tutorials. https://alligator.io/vuejs/intro-to-vuex/. I recently found this repo too. https://github.com/christianmalek/vuex-rest-api

Comment: Thanks for the tip 